# How do you use font forge to generate a font?

Tags: css, fonts

If you want a basic hello world font such as

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: font1;
            src: url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/Sansation_Light.ttf')
            ,url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/Sansation_Light.ttf');
        }
        .myfont{
            font-family: font1;
            font-size: 500%;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="myfont">aA</span>
</body>
</html>
```

and you are using font forge like so:

[image]

You end up with this when you try to "Generate Fonts" it gives you a dialog with all things grayed out.

[image]

I want to export a .ttf file but font forge is not allowing that to happen. [This one](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator/download.html) forces you to pay $80 before you can test it and [many like this](http://ptf.com/.ttf/.ttf+creator/) are probably viruses.

Comment: When I test it, when I click on the button where you have “PS Type 1 (Binary)”, a dropdown with many selectable (and some non-selectable) options available, including “TrueType”. Does SAME ON THIS ONE really mean that you have all options there grayed out? What happens if you click on “Save”?

Comment: http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l493/powerfulcrunch/disabled_zpseeb2e7f1.png

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the first part of the question is just background information, and the problem is just in the use of the FontForge font editor. It seems, from the screen shots, that you have started the creation of a font, selector a character position (letter A) there, and imported a bitmap image. But since the program is in the mode of creating an outline (vector) font, this does not create a glyph. There are no glyphs so far in the font, so there is no selectable option for font format to be used when saving.

If you wish to work with bitmap fonts, see the FontForge information on them, perhaps best starting at http://fontforge.org/editexample7.html#Bitmaps

But bitmap fonts aren’t really what we should be using these days. They don’t scale reasonably to various sizes. Using outline fonts is the way to go, and then you probably need to start from the FontForge introduction: http://fontforge.org/overview.html

I must admit that I find FontForge (both the software itself and its documentation) rather confusing, and it seems to have some oddities and bugs. But as a free font editor, it may well be worth a look.